# Can´t float right my form search image

Tags: html, css

I already tried many ways and I´m not having sucess floating right my search-bar-icon.
 What I´m doing wrong?

Html:

```
<section id="menu-container">
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contats</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                <li id="search_menu">
                   <form name="form1">
                     <input type="search" name="search1" />
                   </form>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
#search_menu search input[type="search"]
{
 background:url(imagens/search-icon-2.png) no-repeat;
 height:62px;
 line-height:62px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJbQ7/)

Just a Small Change

```
.asd
{
  background:url(imagens/search-icon-2.png) no-repeat;
  height:62px;
  line-height:62px;
  float:right;
}

nav{
   float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I want that menu only have 960px, and I want to float right my search form in that 960px, but dont know why its not happening, the search form is floating right but in the 100% of the page. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/3qqMc/

Comment: Thanks, now its working I´ve put the form inside <nav id="menu">. By the way,you know How i can hide the input field? Because I just want to show the icon. And then I´ll try to, when I click in the search icon the input field opens, maybe with jquery or something.

Comment: Using CSS: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/

Comment: Thank you, and I understand now why my div not float to right. Because I´m using the search icon and the input is float to right but the icon no, and I want the icon float in right. Theres no way to hide the input field so my icon can float in right? sorry to be bothering!